# View arrays from a DynamoDB table in QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-quicksight

I wanted to visualise my data in QuickSight. I created a DynamoDB table and stored it in Athena. Then used that Athena as data source in QuickSight.

I have a column in my table that is displaying arrays of objects. That is the main column which I want to visualise.

But in QuickSight it is showing `data type not supported`.

Is there any way we can view arrays in QuickSight?

Comment: Can you share the schema of the table in Athena?

Comment: As of my knowledge, Amazon QuickSight does not support direct visualization of nested data types. But you can flatten your data and extract specific fields so that QuickSight can read.